# What is this musical symbol (inverted "Z" inside a staff)

Tags: notation, rests

Can anyone identify the symbol circled in the image below? It's from a piece of piano music.

[image: A measure of music with: a crotchet, a minim, and a symbol that looks something like an inverted "Z". This symbol is circled.]

Answer (score 19):

Ordinary quarter rest in a somewhat uncommon but not unheard-of style.  French publisher?

Comment: That's nothing -- wait 'til you run into scores (also French, usually) where the flags are backwards!

Comment: Sometimes you will also see what looks just like a backwards eighth rest -- like what you circled above but without the bottom part.  That is also a quarter rest.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Brilliantly put, I'm going to use that one! By night I'm a musician, but by day I'm an engineer from the UK, and my pet peeve is that Americans insist on calling them "English" units when the correct term is "US Customary." The US gallon, for example is completely different from the British gallon (which of course has fell out of use years ago.) But which of these makes more sense: `A B H C` or `A Bb B C`?? We all like to be different in some way or other ;-)

Comment: @steveverrill The term that can be memorized well. Some guys insist on do, re, mi or even ut, re mi. So, what?!

Comment: @steveverrill Interestingly, the B H in German notation comes from earlier times, when tritones were forbidden as "diabolus in musica" in sacred music.  The way to avoid a tritone was to distinguish between "square b" or B natural when using with an E and "round b" or B flat when using with an F.  From these, we get our natural and flat signs.  German H reflects the natural sign, and German B reflects the flat sign.  Oh, and by the way, we Americans have our pet peeves at UK insistences too, "Mitchigan" being among them.  :)

Comment: @BobRodes Wow, that is a very interesting bit of music trivia to have emerged from off-topic nationalistic banter! BTW, I always say "Mishigan", "BirmingHAM" (Alabama) and "BIRMINGham" (UK) ;-)

Comment: If some self-important toff attempts to correct you on Michigan, you can always mention that it is a French transliteration of the Native American Meesheega, meaning "great water", and encourage him to improve his education. :)

Comment: @LevelRiverSt the gallon may have fallen out of use, but the imperial system of measurement is alive and well in the UK, as you will quickly realize if you discuss with anyone from the US the size of a pint or the number of ounces it contains.  But calling US units "English" is perfectly justified as England is the source of these units.  We just missed the innovation of the imperial system because we had already left the empire by that point.

Answer (score 5):

As there are 4 beats in the bar, it has to be a crotchet (quarter note ) rest. It's probably easier to draw than the regular one, but there is an alternative which is the opposite way round to the quaver rest, again, easier to write.